# DataAnnotations missing attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, data-annotations

I have `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` at the top of the file, but essentially the only attributes I have are `[DisplayName]` and `[Readonly]`. Even `[Display(Name...]` does not exist. What am I missing?

Comment: What's the problem again?

Comment: Attributes that usually come with `DataAnnotations` like `[Required]` don't exist?

Comment: `Required` exists right here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx...

Comment: `DisplayName` is part of `System.ComponentModel` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx)).

Comment: @meike Yes, and that is the problem. I can't access what's supposed to exist on my project, even though I've included the references and `using` statements. For example, I can't even do something like `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute;`--the `ValidationAttribute` part will be red underlined, giving me an error saying that it doesn't exist in the namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

Comment: You cannot use a full class name in the `using` statement.

Comment: @meilke Alright, that makes sense. But I can't use anything off of this namespace in the actual code.

Comment: @idlackage Make sure you have *assembly references* to both System.dll and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll.

Comment: @Levi Ahh, that seems to be it, thank you! I don't seem to have a System.dll to include in the references though.

Answer (score 0):

Tools like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) allow you to analyze the `using` statements in a code file.

If you find that you do not need the `using` statement, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following namespaces:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```